# Rest Api Ajax Get запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, rest

Не могу отправить правильный запрос на сервер, чтобы получить с него ответь в виде json строки.

Код:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

При попытке отправки запроса вылетает ошибка:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Comment: На сервере к которому вы отправляете запрос, должен отдаваться header с `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Тем самым сервер говорит, что к нему можно удаленные запросы осуществлять, по дефолту они отключены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть [cors](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) заключается в том что сервер разрешает вам делать запросы с других доменов. В заголовке **ответа** должен приходить список доверенных доменов, поэтому на сервере должно быть прописанно что то вроде

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");
```

или

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

но это не безопасно